# How to convert line with UNIQUE INDEX key words from mySql to H2

Tags: java, mysql, testing, h2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Account (
  `userId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ICQ` INT NULL,
  `home_address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `work_address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `skype` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `additional_info` VARCHAR(450) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`))
 UNIQUE INDEX `userID_UNIQUE` (`userId` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Account';
```

how to convert this line:  `UNIQUE INDEX`userID_UNIQUE`(`userId`ASC)` from mySQL syntax to H2 syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the site [h2database.com](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#index_column) :

```
ALTER TABLE Account ADD CONSTRAINT userID_UNIQUE UNIQUE(userId);
```

Comment: So, I should use separate Statement to execute the Table alteration. Is it possible to excute "unique userId... "  in the same statement ? @YCF_L

Comment: yes @BernardCasey you can try to use `create table t(..., UNIQUE KEY userID_UNIQUE  (userId))`

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Account` (\
  `userId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,\
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,\
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,\
  `ICQ` INT NULL,\
  `home_address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,\
  `work_address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,\
  `skype` VARCHAR(45) NULL,\
  `additional_info` VARCHAR(450) NULL,\
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId` ASC)\
  UNIQUE KEY userID_UNIQUE(userId)
 );
I tried above, it doen't  work ((

Comment: @BernardCasey i think you miss a comma `PRIMARY KEY (userId ASC),
        UNIQUE KEY userID_UNIQUE(userId) `